# Can't override 'sys.excepthook'

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to override `sys.excepthook` exception handling. However, it simply not works.

This is the code I am running.

```py
from sys import excepthook

excepthook = lambda type, exception, traceback : print('foo')

raise Exception('bar')
```

The following code calls my overriden method:

```py
from sys import excepthook

excepthook = lambda type, exception, traceback : print('foo')

try:
    raise Exception('bar')
except Exception as e:
    excepthook(Exception, e, e._traceback_)
```

This code is useless due to the fact `sys.excepthook` should catch unhandled exceptions.

I`m aware many people is having issues such as mine, however, none of the issues helped me solve my problem.

[why-doesnt-sys-excepthook-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495028/why-doesnt-sys-excepthook-work)

[adding-function-to-sys-excepthook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415463/adding-function-to-sys-excepthook)

[sys-excepthook-vs-handled-exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001647/sys-excepthook-vs-handled-exceptions)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

The problem is in importing `sys`module.

```py
import sys

sys.excepthook = lambda type, exception, traceback : print('foo')
```

And not this:

```py
from sys import excepthook
```

It seems python does not know about `excepthook`  function from `sys`so it declares a new variable called `excepthook`. That`s why it does not work as stated in docs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `excepthook` and everything with how names work in Python.

Comment: @L3viathan Yes. That`s what this answer says. Thanks.